# Pandas Dataframe groupby aggregate functions and difference between max and min of a column on the fly

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'a': ['xxx', 'xxx','xxx','yyy','yyy','yyy'], 'start': [10000, 10500, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)


df_new = df.groupby("a",as_index=True).agg(
            ProcessiveGroupLength=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="count"),
            StartMin=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="min"),
            StartMax=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="max"),
            )
```

gives

```
>>>df_new
     ProcessiveGroupLength  StartMin  StartMax
a
xxx                      3     10000     11000
yyy                      3     12000     14000
```

How to get below on the fly, since I think on the fly it will be faster.

```
>>>df_new
     ProcessiveGroupLength    Diff
a
xxx                      3      1000
yyy                      3      2000
```

Below code gives the following error message:

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 5, in 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'*

```
df_new = df.groupby("a").agg(
            ProcessiveGroupLength=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="count"),                
            Diff=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="max"-"min"),)
```

Comment: you'd actually be surprised, but performing the subtraction afterwards will probably be your most performant result. This is because by adding in another aggregator, you're asking pandas to find the min and max twice for each group. Once for the StartMin, once for the StartMax, then 2 more times whne calculating the Diff.

Comment: @CameronRiddell Thanks,. In fact, I want to find the difference in the most fastest and efficient way.   Therefore I removed unnecessary columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution should be changed by lambda function, but I think if many groups or/and large DataFrame this should be slowier like first solution.

Reason is optimalized functions `max` and `min` and also vectorized subtraction of `Series`. In another words if not used lambda functions aggregations is faster.

```
df_new = df.groupby("a").agg(
            ProcessiveGroupLength=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="count"),
            Diff=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc=lambda x: x.max() - x.min()),)
```

Or yu can use [`numpy.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html):

```
df_new = df.groupby("a").agg(
            ProcessiveGroupLength=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="count"),
            Diff=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc=np.ptp),)
```

---

```
print (df_new)
     ProcessiveGroupLength  Diff
a                               
xxx                      3  1000
yyy                      3  2000
```

**Performance**: Depends of data, here is used 1k groups in 1M rows:

```
np.random.seed(20)

N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'start':np.random.randint(10000, size=N)})
print (df)

In [229]: %%timeit
     ...: df_new = df.groupby("a",as_index=True).agg(
     ...:             ProcessiveGroupLength=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="count"),
     ...:             StartMin=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="min"),
     ...:             StartMax=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="max"),
     ...:             ).assign(Diff = lambda x: x.pop('StartMax') - x.pop('StartMin'))
     ...:             
69 ms ± 728 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [230]: %%timeit
     ...: df_new = df.groupby("a").agg(
     ...:             ProcessiveGroupLength=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="count"),
     ...:             Diff=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc=lambda x: x.max() - x.min()),)
     ...:             
172 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [231]: %%timeit
     ...: df_new = df.groupby("a").agg(
     ...:             ProcessiveGroupLength=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc="count"),
     ...:             Diff=pd.NamedAgg(column='start', aggfunc=np.ptp),)
     ...:             
171 ms ± 3.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Your solution with "assign" seems to be better than the other two solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Why lambda x: x.pop('StartMax') - x.pop('StartMin') is faster than np.ptp?

Comment: @burcak - I guess under the hood is used `x.max() - x.min())`

Comment: @burcak - Assign is instead `df_new['Diff'] = df_new.pop('StartMax') - df_new.pop('StartMin')`, `pop` is used for avoid delete columns in next step.